# Access module on nuxt custom hook

Tags: nuxt.js

Is it possible to access a module on a custom hook?

I have the following code:

nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  hooks: {
    build: {
      done(builder) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to access axios inside the done method, like this `this.$axios.$get()`, but I got error stating that this is undefined.